# Probability of an event at the outcome of a binary source

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, information-theory

Let a binary (and independent) source $S$ generating a binary sequence with the following probabilities: $p$ for the symbol '0' and $1-p$ for the symbol '1'.

What is the probability that $S$ gives $n$ consecutive zeros? How to estimate or measure $P(A)$ empirically (e.g., through simulations)?

N.B: on a block of $M$ successive zeros, the count of $n$ consecutive zeros is $\lfloor M/n \rfloor$.

Comment: Unclear definition of $A:$ Suppose $n = 5.$  Does occurrence of $A$ require five (or more) consecutive 0's somewhere along an infinite sequence? Or somewhere among the first 100? Or specifically, starting at index 12?

Comment: @BruceET The question is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for P(A) at any given time at least 5 steps into the sequence, then it is simply $p^5$, 5 consecutive events of probability, p.

As to how to estimate P(A) via simulation, I would have a computer generate a sequence of some length, say 1,000,004.  Then I would have the computer count the number of 5-in-row sequences of zero.  Note that a sequence of M zeros (M>5) would actually entail a quantity of (M-4) 5-zero sequences.  Example 0100000011100000 would have 3 sequences (the final 5 zeros plus two 5-zero sequences in the 6-zero sequence).  Then divide that count by (length-4).  In the contrived example $\hat{P(A)} = \frac{3}{16-4} = \frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{4}$

An interesting check would be to estimate p as well.  For that just divide total 0s over the length.  In the above example, $\hat{p}=\frac{12}{16}=\frac{3}{4}$  How well do these agree?  $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^5 \approx 0.237$, which is not too far from 0.25 (above).  If they disagreed too significantly it might suggest that the sequence is not sufficiently random (or just not long enough for things to average out).

Comment: You seem to be conflating the *expected number* of sequences with the *probability that some sequence occurs.*  The latter is what the question asks for--and the answer is neither $p^5$ nor $p^n.$  Indeed, the question concerns an infinite sequence and it implies (although doesn't explicitly say) that the terms are independent.  When that's the case, $A$ has probability $1$ of occurring whenever $p\gt 0.$

Comment: Ahh, I took the question to be "at any given" step, what are the odds that a length 5 sequence had been generated then.  Yes, for an infinite sequence, any sequence of non-zero probability events would be certain (probability 1) to occur.

Comment: @MikeP Thank you, you thoroughly understood the question. But one crucial detail: on a block of $M$ successive zeros, the count of $n$ consecutive zeros is $\lfloor M/n \rfloor$. So following the example above, there are two blocks of 5 successive zeros instead of three.